# Third rock from the Sun

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

The answer to the puzzle is one or two words.

[image]

Comment: Hmm. I must be doing some very weird thing wrong, because I'm pretty sure I have the second word but not the first...

Comment: Ah, wait, I misread at least one thing.

Comment: (And miscounted one. Duh.)

Comment: First, I would say that @GarethMcCaughan's answer is correct, but what I'm curious about is ... Why did you pick this particular subject for this puzzle?

Comment: @3D1T0R I typically write puzzles for some events, not standalone puzzles, and this one I wrote for a space-themed event.

Comment: @MariiaMykhailova: OK. ... But I actually meant more specifically. Why did you pick rot13(Pnchg Gevnathyv)?

Comment: @3D1T0R Ah, that's just the side effect of the way puzzle was constructed. Svefg V cvpxrq nf znal vqragvsvnoyr cvpgherf nffbpvngrq jvgu rnpu cynarg, naq gura V ybbxrq sbe n fcnpr-eryngrq grez juvpu pbhyq or jevggra hfvat gur cvpgherf V unq. Fbzr cynargf jrer erny obggyrarpxf!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are

> CAPUT TRIANGULI.

To get this,

> first identify the individual solar-system bodies as done by El-Guest. (Reader, if you like my answer, go and upvote El-Guest's.) Then number them (sun=0, Mercury=1, ..., Pluto=9) to get 1-digit and 2-digit numbers. Then convert to letters using A1Z26.

Answer (score 14):

Similar to @QuantumTwinkie, are you

> Solar System?

From the top

> **Earth**worm, Freddie **Mercury**, **Mercury**, **Saturn** 
>  **Venus** De Milo, **Mercury**, **Venus** Fly Trap, **Sun**screen 
>  **Venus** Williams, **Sun**flower, **Mercury** probe, **Neptune** 
>  **Pluto** the Dog, **Mercury** quarter, Sailor **Mercury**, **Mars** bar 
>  **Uran**ium, **Venus** razors, **Mercury** 
>  **Mercury** automobiles, Birth of **Venus**, **Pluto**

Comment: Ahh good answer :D +1, also (a little late) congrats on 10,000!

Comment: Thanks, @QuantumTwinkie!! Been a fun ride so far, we definitely think very alike!! :D

Comment: No. Trust me, I'm too lazy to put up that many pictures to denote something that simple :-)

Answer (score 6):

Are you

> Planets?

1

> Mercury the element and the coin and sailor Merucry.

2

> Venus painting and Venus fly trap and Venus Williams.

3

> earth has American satellites.

4

> Mars bar.

5

> Jupiter

6

> Saturn

7

> Unranus and uranium.

8

> Neptune

9(sort of)

> Pluto the dog

Title

> earth is the third rock from the sun.

Comment: That's Sailor Mercury, not Sailor Moon, just FYI.

Comment: No. Trust me, I'm too lazy to put up that many pictures to denote something that simple :-)

Comment: Sending a +1 right back at you! Partner in crime, with our similar response times

Comment: The Sun isn't a planet!

Comment: Yeah... I realized that there were sun themed pictures later :)